# Converting a single comma separated row into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, split

I am trying to convert a single comma-separated row (column) into multiple rows by using this query:

```
SELECT 
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS String  
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(cast([csvdata] as Varchar(max)), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  
         tboutbound 
     WHERE 
         id = '30') AS A 
CROSS APPLY 
    String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

But I get an error:

> "XML parsing: line 2, character 36, illegal name character"

It is not possible to update table and change the data?

Any suggestion?

Comment: What does csv data looks like? And what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The best advice is to *not* store such text to begin with. Process the text when loading the data and store it properly, in separate columns. In SQL Server 2016 and later you can use STRING_SPLIT. It's still better to design the table properly and split the data when loading it, not after it's already in the database

Comment: @SalmanA It is not possible to paste data here but data contains spaces, apostrophe ( 's) and it may contain some special characters.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is not possible to change data store method. I am not using SQL server 2016.

Comment: @SalmanA I am using SQL Server 2014 ( version 12.0.6108.1 )

Comment: Does the data contain `<`, `>` or `&`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (hoping) that the data does not contain the sequence `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` you could do this:

```
SELECT CAST('<M><![CDATA[' + REPLACE([csvdata], ',', ']]></M><M><![CDATA[') + ']]></M>' AS XML)
FROM t
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0409a8643577a8b88e326689ab6da5a7

Comment: Or escape the text like this: `. . . REPLACE( (select csvdata for xml path(''), type), ',',', ' . . .`

Comment: Thanks David. The Query from DB fiddle giving some result but that is not what I am expecting. The query converted one column into multiple rows but its again values are coming in one column only. e.g. I have one column and one row which is converting into 1 column and 2000 rows. The result should 26 columns with multiple rows.